# Load GIF from WWW.texture in Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

In my game, I get link image from Facebook, and then I use WWW.texture to download an image. But WWW.texture supports only PNG and JPG so I can't load GIF image.

How can I load a GIF file?

Answer (score 1):

Download to local machine using standard C# WebClient (I'm pretty sure it's supported in MONO):

```
//.. Imported from System.Net
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadFile(@"http://www.facebook.com/superhappyimage.gif",@"C:\image.gif");
```

Reading GIFs is another issue entirely.  You could try a 3rd party lib, [Stackoverflow: Animated GIF Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8245089/advanced-gif-library), or you'll need to write your own.  I don't recall Unity having GIF reading in its API but maybe that has changed.

Lastly, Unity does not natively support animated images(GIFs).  Once you parse the gif you need to write your own custom viewer.

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/13156/animated-gif-as-a-texture-on-iphone.html

Comment: Thank u, I want to download image and set it to textture2d, but don't want to store it. So I use function `DownloadData()` of `WebClient`. After run it, my app get crash with error like `System.String doesn't implement interface System.Collections.IEnumerator`. I don't know what reason make it crash?

Comment: @HuyTran I would have to see your implementation.  Throw your code snippet up on pastebin or give me a link so I can download the code that doesn't work.  The problem you're going to have though is that you can't directly put a GIF in to Texture2D.  That's why I said you need a 3rd party library to read the GIF.